# Using unrecommended ElasticSearch version (latest) with Logstash (latest)

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

The latest Logstash (at the time of this question, 1.4.2) recommends using ElasticSearch 1.1.1. There is a note in the documentation:

`VERSION NOTE: Your Elasticsearch cluster must be running Elasticsearch 1.1.1. If you use any other version of Elasticsearch, you should set protocol => http in this plugin.`

The note doesn't illucidate- are there any known issues when running the latest ElasticSearch (at the time of this question, 1.4.0) with the latest Logstash and setting protocol => http?

Comment: I'm not aware of any issues.

Comment: what do you really want to implement?  i didn't meet with any issues in elsaticsearch-1.4.0.

Answer (score 0):

Following the documented rolling upgrade process, I went ahead and upgraded my ES nodes to 1.4 with no problems.

Setting the logstash elasticsearch output protocol to http did cause my logstash server to drop out as a member of the ES cluster, but this doesn't seem to have any consequences.

Comment: Depending on which version of ES you upgrade from, 1.1.1 in my case, you may need to add "http.cors.enabled: true" to your ES config, or you will get cross-origin request errors when using Kibana.